# Can I capture breakpoint event on vscode?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger, vscode-remote

I want to capture a breakpoint event on the debugger adapter in order to create an action in response.

Can it be done?

Comment: there are a few extensions hyou can download and install, depending on what language you are using:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging

Comment: Hi @gianni, unfortunately it does not cover my question. I want to capture when a breakpoint triggers and send an http request to some server following the breakpoint trigger event

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [VS Code API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#debug), the event `onDidChangeBreakpoints` allows to capture the status of the breakpoints

**Example**:

```
const vscode = require('vscode');

context.subscriptions.push(vscode.debug.onDidChangeBreakpoints(
        session => {
            vscode.debug.registerDebugAdapterDescriptorFactory
            console.log("Breakpoint changed");              
        }
    ))
```

`session` contains `added`, `changed` and `removed` properties.